# Meaning `con` for DOS

Tags: windows, command-line

I found a command to create a new text file with contents using:

```
copy con file.txt
Hello World
```

It works similar to `touch` in Linux. However the `con` parameter is not listed in [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490886.aspx). Where can I find more information about this command?

Comment: -1 i'm sure that's absolutely wrong to say it works similar to touch in linux.  You only need to look at the manual of touch to see it doesn't. And copy con prompts for input. Touch does not.  And as for what it stands for, probably console e.g. copy con, copy from the console. hence it prompts for input.

Comment: console tends to mean keyboard mouse and screen.  So copying from the console, in this case, refers to the keyboard. See here too http://www.vfrazee.com/ms-dos/6.22/help/copy.htm  One often sees the terminology of 'console' with KVM switches / extenders / reverse KVMs, to refer to keyb/vid/mouse,  and it applies here too.. In this case, specifically, the keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, the TechNet web page is usually the most comprehensive source for information like this.  Another good source is SS64.com

[An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)

**Edit by barlop**

**Run5K wrote in comment**
"The reference I posted specifically mentions the Copy from the console command  http://ss64.com/nt/copy.html within the Copy syntax options."

Comment: But the prroblem is that I can't find `con` parameter explanation. I decided to ask why not all commands are explained and where can I find them all well described?

Comment: The reference I posted specifically mentions the [Copy from the console](http://ss64.com/nt/copy.html) command within the **Copy** syntax options.  That is essentially the extent of the potential options.  You can find [examples online](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12342764/how-do-i-append-to-a-file-using-the-copy-command) of how people utilize it, but once again the options are rather finite.

Comment: con, com, lpt, aux are device names, that may appear as parameters to dos/cmd commands.

Comment: -1 you haven't even written the answer in your answer, you've just given a link with a reference to every command. If you think you have the answer and that it's in your comment rather than the body of your answer itself, then copy it from your comment into the answer.  But your answer should've had that in there originally, otherwise it's just not an answer just -in your case - a link to documentation on every command.

Comment: @barlop , I appreciate your feedback, but I believe that this question's rather extensive number of edits has become a bit convoluted.  The author's original topic line specifically said *"Where can I find the full reference of DOS commands?"*, and they emphasized that TechNet didn't provide the information they seek.  As a result, I posted my favorite alternate source of complete command line syntax, ensuring that it included information based upon Rafr3's secondary query.  Based upon the original version of the question, it seemed to fit the author's needs rather nicely.

Comment: ok, i've removed my downvote..  while you answer him re full documentation , you still don't specifically address the question he asked in both his original and current question of where specifically to find documentation regarding copy con. You only mentioned it in a comment and should've included it in your answer.